Help needed for verifying 3.3 V wireless charging schematic with LIR927 battery
I am currently working on a small electronics project for my swimming club and could use some advice. Forgive me if this is basic, I'm really new to electronics.
I am working on a wireless charging circuit design and would like to get some advice to ensure everything is correct. This circuit is intended to be powered by a wireless charging coil to charge a 3.3 V LIR927 button battery. Below is the schematic for the wireless charging system:
Components Used and Datasheets:

LDO Regulator: Texas Instruments TPS73533DRVR
Li-ion Charger: Microchip Tech MCP73831T-2ACI/OT
Wireless Power Receiver: Wuxi Chipown Micro-electronics PN7726QF-A1
Coil: Wurth Elektronik 760308101220

My Requirements:

The circuit should safely charge the LIR927 (3.3 V) battery wirelessly.

Questions:

Verification: Could someone please verify if my schematic for the wireless charging system is correct and if all connections are proper?
Improvements: Are there any improvements or changes I should consider to enhance the reliability and efficiency of this design?
Additional Components: Is there any additional component or consideration I might be missing to ensure the circuit operates as intended?

Thank you for your help, even a one or two line response would make my day!
Thanks,
Seán
Here's the schematic:


Did you ever get anywhere with this? I am also new to electronics and I am looking at a similar wireless setup.
